# Is there any way to recover the angular code form dist folder?

Tags: angular

I would like to recover only the TS code (TypeScript code).I lost my application when I tried to pushing the application to GitHub.I didn't have a repository on GitHub (for this application) when I tried to pushing the code.

[View folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X4A5.png)

Answer (score 1):

The code is not saved in the dist folder. Did you delete the rest of your application? If you want to "restore" the dist folder you would just have to rebuild your application with "ng build".

https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: No.I didn't delete my application.I know that in dist folder is not saved the code.The application is currently with the initial code. I am going to put an image in description from this post.

Comment: I want to recover the TypeScript code from the files which are ready for publighing on a web host (in dist folder are the files for deploying).

Comment: Did you try opening the 'app' folder in assets? So src/app/... should contain all the code. https://imgur.com/a/J3WcllN